# Can I change the wal_level from logical to replica? If so are any impact on the replication process?

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-11

Is there a chance to change the wal_level from logical to replica without any impact. I know this involves a restart of services but is this possible?
For example if there is a already a logical replication running with master and slave setup. The question here is can I change the wal_level now from logical to replica(streaming) with the same master and slave.

Answer (score 1):

At least in Postgres 11 you can restart, but `wal_level` does not change if you have slots. You should drop the slots first to do the change (not only subscriptions and publications), losing the replicas.

So if you want to change the `wal_level`, first you could list the slots:

```
select * from pg_replication_slots;
```

and then, drop the slots:

```
select pg_drop_replication_slot('the_name_of_subscriber');
```

for each slot.

Once you drop all slots and change the the `wal_level` to `replica`, you can't make replicas. Even `pg_wal` is flushed when data gets old, maybe a couple of minutes after the drop, it doesn't even wait for the reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If you reduce `wal_level` to `replica`, and you have a logical replication slot (as is needed for logical replication), the server will refuse to restart.

This is because `wal_level = logical` is required by logical decoding and logical replication.

If you first drop the subscription and the publication, thereby removing logical replication, the replication slot will be gone, and you can reduce `wal_level`.

To switch from logical to physical replication, you have to re-create the standby server with `pg_basebackup`.